# How do I merge multiple xls files into one dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xls

I have excel files which each have 3 sheets and all same column headers.

I want to merge all so that I get one combined dataframe. This dataframe should have the sheetname,row number and xls filename listed next to the final dataframe.

i tried

```
 import pandas as pd
 dfe = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('abc1.xls', sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
```

this combined all sheets for one of the files but did not write the row numbers or sheetnames next to the data. How can I do the same?

Desired output-

```
Rownumber Sheetname Filename         State Region  Brand   
 1           tig       abc1.xls      CA         S   Go     
 2           con       abc2.xls      IA         A   Po
```

Comment: @ScottBoston this worked but i do not see sheetnames in the final concatenated file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it. I used two functions. The first function reads all sheets within a single Excel file, and adds the sheet name. The second function takes all of the excel files, and uses the first function to read all the sheets in all the files.

```py
from pandas import pd
def read_sheets(filename):
    result = []
    sheets = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None)
    for name, sheet in sheets.items():
        sheet['Sheetname'] = name
        sheet['Row'] = sheet.index
        result.append(sheet)
    return pd.concat(result, ignore_index=True)

def read_files(filenames):
    result = []
    for filename in filenames:
        file = read_sheets(filename)
        file['Filename'] = filename
        result.append(file)
    return pd.concat(result, ignore_index=True)
```

You can call this by providing a list of files to read:

```
files = ['multisheet.xls', 'multisheet2.xls']
read_files(files)
```

For the example I tried it on, it produces a dataframe like this:

```
    A   B  A+B Sheetname  Row         Filename
0   1  10   11    Sheet1    0   multisheet.xls
1   2  11   13    Sheet1    1   multisheet.xls
2   3  12   15    Sheet1    2   multisheet.xls
3   4  13   17    Sheet1    3   multisheet.xls
4   3  10   13    Sheet2    0   multisheet.xls
5   3  11   14    Sheet2    1   multisheet.xls
6   3  12   15    Sheet2    2   multisheet.xls
7   3  13   16    Sheet2    3   multisheet.xls
8   1  10   11    Sheet1    0  multisheet2.xls
9   2  11   13    Sheet1    1  multisheet2.xls
10  3  12   15    Sheet1    2  multisheet2.xls
11  4  13   17    Sheet1    3  multisheet2.xls
12  4  10   13    Sheet2    0  multisheet2.xls
13  3  11   14    Sheet2    1  multisheet2.xls
14  3  12   15    Sheet2    2  multisheet2.xls
15  3  13   16    Sheet2    3  multisheet2.xls
```

Comment: Hi Nick. Thanks for your response. It works exactly how i want it to. but it is missing correlating row numbers from the files and sheets

Comment: In Scotts first comment it worked where the row numbers also showed up from their origin sheets into the final combined file 
df00 = pd.concat([pd.concat(pd.read_excel(f'{f}', sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True).assign(Filename=f'{f}') for f in
           ['abc1.xls', 'abc2.xls', 'abc3.xls']])

Comment: @hartvillezillow Row numbers can be added using `sheet['Row'] = sheet.index`, or by removing `ignore_index=True`. See edit.